# Connecting Wireless Hosts to a Standard Host via AP in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

NED File:

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;
//import inet.physicallayer.commom.packetlevel.Radio;
//import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;

channel Link extends ned.DatarateChannel
{
    parameters:
        int cost = default(0);
}

network clientserverWLAN

{
    parameters:

    string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");
//**.mgmt.numChannels = 2;

    submodules:

        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,50");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,150");

        }
        radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            parameters:

                @display("p=100,250");
        }


        host1: WirelessHost {
            @display("r=,,#707070");

        }
        ap: AccessPoint {
            @display("p=349,167;r=,,#707070");

        }
        server: StandardHost {
            @display("p=224,168;i=device/server");
        }

    connections:
        ap.ethg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  delay = 0.1us; datarate = 10Mbps; } <--> server.ethg++;


}
```

INI File:

```
[General]
network = clientserverWLAN
output-scalar-file-append = false
output-vector-file-append = false
runnumber-width = 0
sim-time-limit = 10s

record-eventlog = true

**.wlan[*].mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtAPSimplified"
**.wlan[*].radioType ="Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium"
#**.wlan[*].radioType ="Ieee80211Nic"
#**.wlan[*].radioType ="IdealWirelessNic"
**.wlan[*].macType = "Ieee80211Mac"
**.wlan*.bitrate = 2Mbps

**.host1.numUdpApps=1
**.host1.udpApp[*].typename="UDPBasicApp"
**.host1.udpApp[*].destAddresses = "server"
**.host1.udpApp[*].destPort = 1000
**.host1.udpApp[*].messageLength = 1000B
**.host1.udpApp[*].startTime = 0s
**.host1.udpApp[*].sendInterval = 10s
**.host1.udpApp[*].stopTime = 300s




**.server.numUdpApps = 1
**.server.udpApp[*].typename="UDPSink"
**.server.udpApp[*].localPort = 1000




**.ap.wlan[*].mac.address = "10:00:00:00:00:00"
**.ap.wlan[*].radio.typename ="Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium" 
#**.ap.wlan[*].radio.typename ="Ieee80211Nic"
#**.ap.wlan[*].radio.typename ="IdealWirelessNic"
**.ap.wlan[*].mgmt.typename = "Ieee80211MgmtAPSimplified"

**.host1.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium"
#**.host1.wlan[*].radio.typename = "Ieee80211Nic"
#**.host1.wlan[*].radio.typename = "IdealWirelessNic"
**.host1.wlan[*].mgmt.typename = "Ieee80211MgmtAPSimplified"
**.mac.address = "auto"
```

Error:

> Submodule radio: No module type named 'Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium'
>   found that implements module interface
>   inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadio (not in the loaded NED
>   files?), at
>   /Users/ashish/omnetpp-5.3/samples/inet/src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/Ieee80211Nic.ned:77
>   -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) clientserverWLAN.host1.wlan[0] (id=42), during network setup

Please help regarding establishing communication between Wireless Host to AP and to Server

Trying to run UDP app

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying the type of the radio channel by replacing

```
radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium
```

with

```
radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium
```